# UWP Treeview missing from toolbox

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have Windows 10 target version Build 17134 and Min version is Creators Update Build 15063

I have Microsoft.UI.Xaml 2.0.18091 installed via Nuget Package Manager

Running VS2017 15.8.6

But I cannot see a TreeView control in the toolbox

[image: error picture]

[Update]

When I try to paste in Xaml from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) I get an error

```
XAML1104 The type 'TreeViewNode' is not available in the target platform minimum version (10.0.15063.0) supported by this project
```

[Update]

I have windows version 1809 and build 17763  [image: windows builds]

I have SDK 10.0.17763

However the only treeview in the tool box is Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls

Comment: have u tried writing xaml for treeview intead? with the namespace "Microsoft.UI.Xaml" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145869/xls0413the-property-itemssource-was-not-found-in-type-treeview

Answer (score 4):

> XAML1104 The type 'TreeViewNode' is not available in the target platform minimum version (10.0.15063.0) supported by this project

The [TreeViewNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17134-api-diff#treeviewnode) class is introduced from Windows 10, Build 17134, it's not available in 15063.

The error message also has explained it. You need to make your project's target/min version is 17134 or higher.

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar issue but as you suggested I have changed the min target version to Build 17134 but still I cannot find TreeView in a ToolBox.

Answer (score 2):

You project must have a min SDK version of 15063 to use `TreeView`. You can change the project target by right-clicking the project node in **Solution Explorer**, going to **Properties** and modifying the two appropriate dropdowns on the first tab.

However, you can now actually use `TreeView` control in earlier versions by virtue of the [Windows UI library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/), which contains latest controls with backporting to older versions.

Comment: I seem to still need Microsoft.UI.Xaml ( i.e The Windows UI Library )  with SDK  17763 to see treeview in the toolbox.